# How can I turn off auto focus when using the remote with my Nikon D7000?

Tags: nikon, autofocus, nikon-d7000, remote

I have a remote with my D7000 and it's hugely frustrating that it auto focuses when using the remote. The whole reason I want it is for speed and to not move the tripod.

I have looked through the settings and turned off auto focus on the lens and body.

Comment: It's been a while since I've had a D7000 but setting the lens to MF mode should disable AF completely, just remember to put it back to AF when done.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't. It will only auto focus when using the remote, if i snap away normally of course there is no auto focus

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off autofocus using the dial at the bottom left side (when looking though the viewfinder), beside the bajonett. Turn it from `AF` to `M` to disable autofocus. You then need to focus the lens manually. You may also auto-focus first, then switch to `M` before using a remote trigger.

[image: Location of the AF-mode dial (sceenshot of the manual page 3)]

(Page 3)

[image: Detail view of the AF-mode dial (sceenshot of the manual page 91)]

(Page 91)

(Source: http://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/26/D7000.html)

Comment: Unfortunately I have already done this.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible yet. you need to do it manually.

Nikon have only two remote device([other also](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/photography-accessories/dslr-camera-accessories.page)):

**ML-L3:** External Remote shutter(infrared ray,Range:5 meter appx.)

**WU-1a:** Wireless remote shutter with cell phone(wifi)

Comment: I wonder why they would make a remote and then not give you control over how you would like to use that remote. Shocked and stunned :O